# How to resolve an import of a java package in a project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I took the source code from a Java Application from [Maxim's iButton OneWireViewer](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/ibutton/software/1wire/1wire_api.cfm). From a [Google code repo](https://code.google.com/p/sparrow-hawk/source/browse/#git%2Fibutton_owapi_1_10%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fdalsemi%2Fonewire), I found the "package" that I need to use for a separate project. They are all the Java files and not `.class` or `.jar`. For this project, the first thing I want to do is be able to run the OneWireViewer Java application through an IDE (Eclipse in my case). Currently, when I try importing `com.dalsemi.onewire.*`, Eclipse tells me the import cannot be resolved. How can I add these java files to my project?

Comment: Check the pom what dependancy jar it needs add that to the class path or your repo and then try the import....

Comment: Try compiling them into .class files and add them to your CLASSPATH.  I'd recommend packaging them as a JAR and adding that as you would any 3rd party JAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you do not want to include any library's source files in your project. You either add their distribution as a dependency in your build-file, or download the distribution and add it to your project.

If I understand your question correctly, you need only a small part of this OneWireViewer. You should still include the entire distribution `.jar`, because you don't know if those classes depend on anything else in that archive.

So, download [the OneWireViewer distribution](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/ibutton/software/1wire/1wire_api.cfm), add the `lib/OneWireAPI.jar` file from the zip to your project in Eclipse as a dependency on the Build path. This should enable you to import the requested package.